# I am trying to configure a Flask app with Nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I am following along with an NGINX tutorial but I am missing something. The IP address (x.x.x.x:8000) of the server works but not the domain name.

upstream flask-app {
server flask:8000;
}

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you type 'example.com' into a browsers address bar your website does not come up? If so have you configured the appropriate DNS records?

Comment: Which domain/host name is not working? example.com or flask-app?